# Trouble with exporting a list to a txt file (formatting problem)

Tags: python, list, formatting, export

Python beginner here, having trouble with formatting when writing a list to a txt file. I want to export my list of books in a specific format, for comparison here is how my list [currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCvmp.png) looks when exported.

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9BbI.png) is how I want it to look. As you can see, we'll need some formatting.

The problem is, whenever I try to use the .replace function I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOus8.png

Here is the code in question. I've removed anything that causes errors.

```
def exportBooks():
    with open ('testbooks.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(books))
            print()
            print("Export complete.")
            print()
```

I have to convert the list into a string or else the export won't work. Perhaps this same thing is linked to the error? What do you think we can do about this? I can post the rest of my code if requested in case you need more information, but does anyone have any ideas on the problem? How should it be coded here? Thank you very much.

**EDIT:** **Thanks everyone,** I was able to fix this issue. The error was caused by a parenthesis error, here is what I went with for the output I wanted:

```
def exportBooks():
    print()
    print("Exporting Inventory")
    print()
    with open ('books.txt', 'w') as f:
            for book in books:
                f.write(str(book).replace("\t",";"))
            print()
            print("Export complete.")
            print()
```

Comment: the code that causes error would be needed to understand whats causing it.. kindly edit your post to include it..

Comment: assuming that books is the list u want to export - convert it to string and remove the first and last character which are the brackets.. `f.write(str(books)[1:-1])` should solve it

Comment: on a side note - after looking at your traceback it seems the original code contained `f.write(str(books)).replace(...)` which wud be undesired for your case, and should instead be `f.write(str(books).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))` (paranthesis error, as i like to call it). i however dont recommend this way as it will replace all `[` and `]` from the string, not just first and last..

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to get the output I wanted, which was f.write(str(book).replace("\t",";")) thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must need to read the first file then write a text file? maybe this one can help you.

```
#first you need to read the file book right here
def exportBooks():
    with open('book.text') as books:
        return books.read().replace(',', ';')

#this will write the content of return value
    with open('write.text', 'w') as w:
        w.write(exportBooks())
```

Comment: I was able to find the output I wanted, f.write(str(book).replace("\t",";"))

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write the python list structure as it is to the file where it includes all the extra characters (e.g. ",", "[", "]"). Instead you have to convert the list object in to a raw string format before writing.
Try following.

```
def exportBooks():
    with open ('testbooks.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("\n".join(books))
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply. This gives me an error message. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Book found

I can fix that error message by adding wrapping the books list in a str tag, but the output is one character per like like so:

[
M

a

s

t

e


Which isn't the output we want.